# The farthest from independent a distribution can be

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I think this is a pretty basic probability question but I'll set it up a bit in order to be more specific.

Let $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of probability distributions with finite second moment. Let $KL(q||p)$ denote Kullback-Liebler divergence (relative entropy). Let $Q \subset P(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the additional restriction that all marginals are independent (i.e. measures in $Q$ are of product form).

Then what is $\max_{p} KL(Q||p)$?

I would imagine we'd pick $p$ to be a distribution where each component describes the same 1-dimensional random variable, i.e. "fully dependent" -- how would you describe this in terms of covariance or correlation? And I guess $\min_{p} KL(Q||p)$ would be a function of the entropy of $p$?

edit: $KL(Q||p) = \min_{q\in Q} KL(q||p)$.

Comment: How do you define $KL(Q\|p)$ given $Q$ is a set of distributions?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio $\min_{q\in Q} KL(q||p)$. added to the question, thanks.